# How can I start / stop setInterval?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, setinterval

I've tried different ways, but It doesn't works.

```
[...]
  const [automatic, setAutomatic] = useState(false);

[...]
  var startAuto;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!automatic) {
      console.log("stop");
      clearInterval(startAuto);
    } else {
      startAuto = setInterval(() => {
        changeQuestion("+");
      }, 5 * 1000);
    }
  }, [automatic]);

[...]
        <Button
          onPress={() => setAutomatic(!automatic)}
          title="turn on/off"
        />
[...]
```

It works when I put a setTimeout outside the useEffect, that way:

```
setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(startAuto); alert('stop'); }, 10000);
```

But I want to have a button to start / stop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `var startAuto;` is redeclared on each render, and since changing the state causes a re-render, it never holds the reference to the interval, which is never cleared.

Use the `useEffect` cleanup function to clear the interval. Whenever `automatic` changes, it would call the `cleanup` (if returned by the previous invocation), and if `automatic` is `true` it would create a new interval loop, and return a new cleanup function of the current interval.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!automatic) return;
  
  const startAuto = setInterval(() => {
    changeQuestion("+");
  }, 5 * 1000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(startAuto);
  };
}, [automatic]);
```

Working example:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const Demo = () => {
  const [automatic, setAutomatic] = useState(false);
  const [question, changeQuestion] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!automatic) return;
    
    const startAuto = setInterval(() => {
      changeQuestion(q => q + 1);
    }, 5 * 100);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(startAuto);
    };
  }, [automatic]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => setAutomatic(!automatic)}
      >
        turn {automatic ? 'off' : 'on'}
      </button>
      
      <p>{question}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Demo />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can check and use this hook:

https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-interval

```js
export default function Component() {
  // The counter
  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0)
  // Dynamic delay
  const [delay, setDelay] = useState<number>(1000)
  // ON/OFF
  const [isPlaying, setPlaying] = useState<boolean>(false)

  useInterval(
    () => {
      // Your custom logic here
      setCount(count + 1)
    },
    // Delay in milliseconds or null to stop it
    isPlaying ? delay : null,
  )

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setDelay(Number(event.target.value))
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setPlaying(!isPlaying)}>
        {isPlaying ? 'pause' : 'play'}
      </button>
      <p>
        <label htmlFor="delay">Delay: </label>
        <input
          type="number"
          name="delay"
          onChange={handleChange}
          value={delay}
        />
      </p>
    </>
  )
}
```